# Pyomo mipgap status monitoring

Tags: pyomo, optimality-gap

Is there a way to monitor the value of the `mipgap` while running an optimization model Pyomo? I would like to know how far I am from the optimality gap. Here is my code:

```
solver = SolverFactory('cbc', executable='path/to/cbc.exe')
solver.options['mipgap'] = 1e-3
solver.options['tee'] = True
solver.options['keepfiles'] = True
results = solver.solve(Model, logfile='path/to/logfile.log')
```

I can report the last value of mipgap AFTER solver is finished as follows:

```
__data = results.Problem._list

LB = __data[0].lower_bound
UB = __data[0].upper_bound
__gap = abs(UB - LB) * 100/max(0.1, abs(UB))
print(__gap)
```

But this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a sort of live streaming from `solver` which updates me about the current value of the `mipgap`; then I can determine how far I am from the optimality; or whether there is any progress in the model.

Comment: Is there no solver log to watch? (Note Jupyter notebooks may not always show this; so try to run locally from the command line).

Comment: There is a log that is stored in logfile='path/to/logfile.log' but it is only accessible once the solver is done; i.e., cannot monitor the value of mip-gap while running solve method.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**: Add this line - `solver.options['slog'] = 1`, before calling the solve method.

**Detailed answer**: In terms of logging, a user needs to pass two arguments to the solver in order to obtain the required. The first argument is `tee=True` that enables the solver logs and the second argument is `slog=1` that defines the logging level. MIP-gap is logged at the `info` level but the default setting is `warning`. So, when you override the default logging level on the solver with the argument `slog`, you get to see those details.

[This](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cbc.1.html) page and some digging inside [cbc's github](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc) helped me figure that out.

Comment: Many thanks, Mohit. I just added `solver.options['slog'] = True; solver.options['tee'] = True; solver.options['keepfiles'] = True` but still nothing happening while running solve! Is it logging the info somewhere or some file? Nothing is happening in the command window!

Comment: I thought I am over-writing it by adding `solver.options['tee'] = True;` afterwards. But removing it and keeping only `solver.options['slog'] = 1` did not change anything.

Comment: The expectation with that is it should print the logs in real-time on your console, just to make sure can you confirm you're not using any kind of package to silence logs in your code at any point?

Comment: I tested on my side, you can utilize these files for reference also another recommendation is to try `slog=3`
https://github.com/mohit-mhjn/py_optimization/tree/master/ad_revenue_optimization

Comment: Many thanks for the response, Mohit. As advised in the example, I added the command `solver.options['slog'] = 1 (and 3)` along with `results = solver.solve(Model, logfile='path/to/logfile.log', tee=True)` but all it did, printing out the final status, including gap of course, AFTER solution was obtained with the requested accuracy. I ran your code as well which did the same. By the way, as checked, I did not have any package to silence logs. By any chance, would it be possible to share a sort of screenshot from your screen to see how your code works?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: results = solver.solve(Model, logfile='path/to/logfile.log', tee=True)

with tee=True, solver will display the log at runtime and you will be able to see the IP solution with the gap%.

Comment: I have tried that Jatin. It prints out the result at the end! I suspect it has to do with solver, i.e., CBC, glpk, etc. I know CPLEX does report intermediate values of gap but not sure of the open source ones

Comment: It works fine with glpk. Didn't test on other one.

Comment: You mean, you can track how the gap is converging to the tolerance,? What I am looking for is something like the following: `solver = SolverFactory('cbc', executable='path/to/cbc.exe')
solver.options['mipgap'] = 1e-5
solver.options['tee'] = True
solver.options['keepfiles'] = True
results = solver.solve(Model, logfile='path/to/logfile.log')` then while (NOT AFTER) running the solver, it prints out `gap: 5%, gap: 2%, gap: 0.5%, gap: 0.02%, ..., gap: 0%,`; then prints out the result upon gap turning to 0%

Comment: I finally managed to make it happen and I thought it worth sharing: Before calling solver (`CBC.exe`)         `solver.options = {'sec': 50000, 'threads': 6,
                                'ratio': solver_gap_ratio,  'slog': 3}` It then prints out all the info